# Unable to override static final variable of a final class using PowerMock

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, powermock, powermockito

I'm trying to use PowerMock Whitebox setInternalState api to override a static final variable of a final class. But it doesn't seems to be working. Please see sample code below:

**A final class with static final variable:**

```
public final class BuildConfig {
    public static final String BUILD_TYPE = "debug";
}
```

**A helper class to return the above variable:**

```
public class BuildConfigHelperClass {
    public String getBuildType() {
        return BuildConfig.BUILD_TYPE;
    }
}
```

**Test class**

```html
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.SuppressStaticInitializationFor;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;
import org.powermock.reflect.Whitebox;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.mockStatic;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@SuppressStaticInitializationFor("BuildConfig")
@PrepareForTest({BuildConfigHelperClassTest.class, BuildConfigHelperClass.class, BuildConfig.class})
public class BuildConfigHelperClassTest {

    private BuildConfigHelperClass subject;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        subject = new BuildConfigHelperClass();
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldReturnDebugBuildType() {
        assertEquals("debug", subject.getBuildType());
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldReturnProductionBuildType() {
        mockStatic(BuildConfig.class);
        Whitebox.setInternalState(BuildConfig.class, "BUILD_TYPE", "production");
        assertEquals("production", subject.getBuildType());
    }
}
```

In above test class, for second test `subject.getBuildType()` method should return "production" as I am overriding it through Whitebox, but it always fails because of return value i.e. "debug".

Can anyone please guide me on what I'm missing.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is optimizing the code, where this:

```
public class BuildConfigHelperClass {
    public String getBuildType() {
         return BuildConfig.BUILD_TYPE;
   }
}
```

is essentially compiled to:

```
public class BuildConfigHelperClass {
    public String getBuildType() {
         return "debug";
   }
}
```

so the unit test is running against compiled code which has no reference to BuildConfig.

Instead of referencing `BUILD_TYPE` directly, try adding a static getter:

```
public final class BuildConfig {
    private static final String BUILD_TYPE = "debug";

    public static final String getBuildType() {
        return BUILD_TYPE;
    }
}
```

Then the static method can be mocked:

```
@Test
public void shouldReturnProductionBuildType() {
    mockStatic(BuildConfig.class);
    // Whitebox.setInternalState(BuildConfig.class, "BUILD_TYPE", "production");
    PowerMockito.when(BuildConfig.getBuildType()).thenReturn("production");
    assertEquals("production", subject.getBuildType());
}
```

This test works on my local, although other compilers might still be able to optimize it away and break the test.

Comment: Thanks for the approach which works fine. But what if we don't have any control over the BuildConfig class to modify it (In my case I can't modify it). Then this approach can't be used.

Comment: Since `BUILD_TYPE` is defined as static final the value of a unit test which attempts to manipulate it is questionable.